# User implemented throttling in postgres

Tags: postgresql, throttling, database-deadlocks

What I did so far is a function which takes throttling id and interval, and returns `true` if function is called **more than once for a given interval**. Otherwise it returns `null`.

This works as expected when testing, but in stronger workloads it gives errors,

```
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
===> - CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (2,108) in relation "shared"
    SQL function "throttle" statement 1
```

Any suggestion how to avoid deadlocks?

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION monitor.throttle(id_i text, every_i interval)
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$

    with
    nv as (
      select id_i id,
        '1'::text val,
        every_i every,
        clock_timestamp() modtime
    ),
    upsert as (
        update monitor.shared m set
          modtime = case
            when m.modtime+every >nv.modtime then m.modtime
            else nv.modtime
          end
        FROM nv
        WHERE m.id = nv.id
        RETURNING m.*
    ),
    ins as (
        INSERT INTO monitor.shared (id,modtime,val)
          SELECT id,modtime,val FROM nv
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM upsert up WHERE up.id = nv.id
          )
        returning *
    )
    select
        case
            -- don't throttle
            when i.id is not null or u.modtime=nv.modtime then null
            -- throttle
            else true
        end
    from nv
    left join upsert u on true
    left join ins i on true

$function$
```

---

```
\d monitor.shared
               Unlogged table "monitor.shared"
 Column  |           Type           |       Modifiers
---------+--------------------------+------------------------
 id      | text                     | not null
 val     | text                     |
 modtime | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
Indexes:
    "shared_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: Note `monitor.shared` is unlogged as docs suggest such tables should perform better.

Comment: There is no deadlock.  There is a statement timeout.  If you want to make your query intentionally slow, then you probably should not set statement_timeout as well

Comment: @jjanes thank you for your input. Is that issue related to the top most statement invoked by the client?

Comment: Yes, I would assume so.  It would be great if you could show some simplified example of how you are using the function in the top level statement.  Also, if you are not intentionally setting statement_timeout, then your admin must be doing it for you.

Comment: There are one or two functions on top of stack doing various business logic, and thus taking some time to execute. If concurrent queries are waiting for ALL this to finish, increasing statement timeout would not solve the issue in acceptable manner. Could some isolation level decouple execution of this function from rest of the statement, so concurrent queries don't hit table row/tuple lock?